# Jenkins run up an Amazon EC2 Linux Ubuntu instance failing

Tags: java, linux, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I have configured and tried to run Jenkins System Configuration from AWS windows system:

It is failed and thrown the fallowing error.

I insalled manually Java 1.7

---

```
Jun 29, 2018 6:22:29 PM null
FINEST: Node RocketChat-Server (i-034fb93609641e1b1)(i-034fb93609641e1b1) is still pending/launching, waiting 5s
Jun 29, 2018 6:22:35 PM null
FINEST: Node RocketChat-Server (i-034fb93609641e1b1)(i-034fb93609641e1b1) is still pending/launching, waiting 5s
Jun 29, 2018 6:22:40 PM null
FINEST: Node RocketChat-Server (i-034fb93609641e1b1)(i-034fb93609641e1b1) is still pending/launching, waiting 5s
Jun 29, 2018 6:22:45 PM null
FINEST: Node RocketChat-Server (i-034fb93609641e1b1)(i-034fb93609641e1b1) is still pending/launching, waiting 5s

Jun 29, 2018 6:22:50 PM null
FINER: Node RocketChat-Server (i-034fb93609641e1b1)(i-034fb93609641e1b1) is ready
Jun 29, 2018 6:22:50 PM null
INFO: Launching instance: i-034fb93609641e1b1
Jun 29, 2018 6:22:50 PM null
INFO: bootstrap()
Jun 29, 2018 6:22:50 PM null
INFO: Getting keypair...
Jun 29, 2018 6:22:50 PM null
INFO: Using key: FirstKeyPair
e8:59:89:73:4b:c5:55:1a:f9:18:85:95:a7:53:4c:a4:27:a1:a2:26
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEogIBAAKCAQEAlZa6EHKfbQ2Fro4pEVhb/rPwlDRpZoUYZTVzzFbLTSajMTYj3PaiZzTBcLlY
lmiJfb7wtIJJ/xo9/SxdUXZHK6b3JBrfHUH7TVGW060ugeeJmfb
Jun 29, 2018 6:22:50 PM null
INFO: Authenticating as ubuntu
Jun 29, 2018 6:22:50 PM null
INFO: Connecting to ec2-35-178-118-236.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com on port 22, with timeout 10000.

Jun 29, 2018 6:22:59 PM null
INFO: Failed to connect via ssh: There was a problem while connecting to ec2-35-178-118-236.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:22
Jun 29, 2018 6:22:59 PM null
INFO: Waiting for SSH to come up. Sleeping 5.

Jun 29, 2018 6:23:04 PM null
INFO: Connecting to ec2-35-178-118-236.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com on port 22, with timeout 10000.

Jun 29, 2018 6:23:04 PM null
INFO: Connected via SSH.
Jun 29, 2018 6:23:04 PM null
INFO: connect fresh as root
Jun 29, 2018 6:23:04 PM null
INFO: Connecting to ec2-35-178-118-236.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com on port 22, with timeout 10000.
Jun 29, 2018 6:23:05 PM null
INFO: Connected via SSH.
Jun 29, 2018 6:23:05 PM null
INFO: Creating tmp directory (/tmp) if it does not exist

Jun 29, 2018 6:23:06 PM null
INFO: Verifying: java -fullversion
bash: java: command not found
Jun 29, 2018 6:23:06 PM null
INFO: Installing: sudo yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64
sudo: yum: command not found
Jun 29, 2018 6:23:06 PM null
WARNING: Failed to install: sudo yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64
Jun 29, 2018 6:23:06 PM null
INFO: Verifying: which scp
/usr/bin/scp
Jun 29, 2018 6:23:06 PM null
INFO: Copying slave.jar to: /tmp
Jun 29, 2018 6:23:06 PM null
INFO: Launching slave agent (via Trilead SSH2 Connection):  java  -jar /tmp/slave.jar
ERROR: SSH channel is closed
```

> java.io.IOException: SSH channel is closed
>           at >com.trilead.ssh2.channel.ChannelManager.ioException(ChannelManager.java:1543)
>           at >com.trilead.ssh2.channel.ChannelManager.sendData(ChannelManager.java:373)
>           at >com.trilead.ssh2.channel.ChannelOutputStream.write(ChannelOutputStream.java:63)
>           at hudson.remoting.BinarySafeStream$2._write(BinarySafeStream.java:272)
>           at hudson.remoting.BinarySafeStream$2.write(BinarySafeStream.java:255)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(Unknown Source)
>           at >java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeClassDesc(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFatalException(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
>           at hudson.remoting.Capability.writePreamble(Capability.java:142)
>           at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.negotiate(ChannelBuilder.java:388)
>           at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.build(ChannelBuilder.java:354)
>           at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.setChannel(SlaveComputer.java:415)
>           at >hudson.plugins.ec2.ssh.EC2UnixLauncher.launch(EC2UnixLauncher.java:217)
>           at >hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2ComputerLauncher.launch(EC2ComputerLauncher.java:122)
>           at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$1.call(SlaveComputer.java:288)
>           at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
>           at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$2.call(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:71)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>           Suppressed: java.io.IOException: SSH channel is closed
>               at com.trilead.ssh2.channel.ChannelManager.ioException(ChannelManager.java:1543)
>               at com.trilead.ssh2.channel.ChannelManager.sendData(ChannelManager.java:373)
>               at com.trilead.ssh2.channel.ChannelOutputStream.write(ChannelOutputStream.java:63)
>               at hudson.remoting.BinarySafeStream$2._write(BinarySafeStream.java:272)
>               at hudson.remoting.BinarySafeStream$2.write(BinarySafeStream.java:255)
>               at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(Unknown Source)
>               at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
>               at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
>               at hudson.remoting.Capability$1.close(Capability.java:132)
>               at hudson.remoting.Capability.writePreamble(Capability.java:144)
>               ... 12 more
>           Caused by: java.io.IOException: Close requested by remote
>               at com.trilead.ssh2.channel.Channel.setReasonClosed(Channel.java:331)
>               at com.trilead.ssh2.channel.ChannelManager.msgChannelClose(ChannelManager.java:1254)
>               at com.trilead.ssh2.channel.ChannelManager.handleMessage(ChannelManager.java:1475)
>               at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.receiveLoop(TransportManager.java:809)
>               at >com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager$1.run(TransportManager.java:502)
>               ... 1 more
>         [CIRCULAR REFERENCE:java.io.IOException: Close requested by remote]

---

Comment: so is it Linux or windows - you say linux in the title and then call it 'AWS windows system'

Comment: This is first time I started exploring Jenkins and Amazon Web Services. I was trying to connect to linux ubuntu  from aws -windows mechine using Jenkins.

Comment: The root of the error is `bash: java: command not found`, get Java setup correctly and this should all be resolved. The error comes from not finding java, attepting to install it, and then failing to install it automatically.

Comment: I am just back to close the issue as it is the issue with java version 8 requirement. Thanks